# Azure DevOps: Build - Configuration Get Sources step (TFVC)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, tfvc

Is it possible to configure the "***Server Path***" field as a variable in the *Get Sources* step for TFVC (in Azure DevOps)?
[image]

I would like to trigger this build remotely via REST API with a specific branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support configuring "Server Path" field as variable in Get Sources step for TFVC. If you want to trigger a build with specific branch, you could enable [CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/tfvc?view=azure-devops#ci-triggers). In CI trigger, you could select the version control paths you want to include and exclude. But you need to make sure that these paths are in your TFVC mappings.

In conclusion, it's not able to dynamically set workspace mapping path based on the branch which continuous integration trigger your build pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's a design limitation that is unlikely to change as neither TFVC nor "classic" JSON pipelines are a priority for Microsoft at this point; TFVC has been supplanted by Git and classic pipelines have been supplanted by YAML pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

We have this working without any problems in Azure DevOps Server 2019 and 2020 for manually triggering the build from the web UI, so it should also work via REST API. We're using a mapping of the form:
`$/folderA/$(branch)/Source` -> `localFolderA\localFolderB` [with the pipeline variable `branch`]